# 1.9.3 & SUPEE-8788 versions

Tags: supee-8788, ce-1.9.3.0, magento1.9.3

I was running CE1.9.2.4 and I did SUPEE-8788 v1. I then did a full upgrade to 1.9.3.

Now I'm running 1.9.3 and SUPEE-8788 v1. Do I still need to back out SUPEE-8788 v1 and do SUPEE-8788 v2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything when you upgraded to 1.9.3.0. Patch 8788 is included in the release.

From https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

> Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
>       SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788

Any changes made to the core files are overwritten when you upgrade. You can consider your install as a fresh 1.9.3.0 with above patches applied. So you won't need to do anything regarding Patch 8788.